# cannot use the list.remove function within a class: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class named "mdp" and a "self.actions=[]" list has been initialized in the initialization function:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.actions = [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0, -1)]
```

Then I use the self.action in another function within the class mdp:

```
def Exploration(self, s):
    exploit_act = self.pick_best(s)
    temp_list = self.actions.remove(exploit_act)
    ...
```

For sure, the "exploit_act" here is (0, 1), but there is an error is :

```
   list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I used the remove() function outside the class, and it works normally. But within the class, it has error. I doubt because the variable type of self.actions or whatever else. Thanks for this help!

Comment: Check for removing the same value twice. And `list.remove()` always returns `None`, so `temp_list` will not contain result of removal.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I remove the same value twice. Then I tried to use the remove result directly like random.choice(temp_list.remove(act)), then it we still wrongs.  Cause the return value is None. I fixed it already, thanks a lot!